# Is there a way to make scrollPhysics to be the same as in ListView for Column widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

The reason I'm asking is because I don't want to have a `ListView` I have a `Column` which fits me perfectly however the inability to scroll makes my app look irresponsive. How could I add my `Column` a more fluid scrollPhysics please?

I know that Column gets 100% of height of the screen and that's perfectly fine I just want to give it a responsive feel.

Answer (score 0):

Warp the `Column` with `SingleChildScrollView` so that the `Column` will be scrollable, and you can specify the scroll `scrollPhysics`.

Comment: Thanks it gives me an error: `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.` though.

Comment: It depends on widget structure you use. First, wrap `SingleChildScrollView` with `Expanded`.

Comment: Yeah just as what  BambinoUA said or you can warp the Colum with a Container and give it the height of the screen or any fixed height < screen height.